# Bootstrap Navbar Links Disabled on Ease-In

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a top sticky navbar on a Bootstrap 4 page that is set to ease-in/reveal after scrolling down the page. However when the navbar shows itself, no links function, not even :hover changed the link colors. I used media queries since I want this only to hide itself at first on desktop. This is my code, a draft can be found [here.](https://www.activatebody.com/v2/testhome.html)

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-home {
      opacity: 1!important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-home {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  }
}
```

Javascript:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // scroll functions
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        if($(window).width() >= 768) 

            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= 150) {
                $('.navbar-home').addClass("navbar-hide");
            } else {
                $('.navbar-home').removeClass("navbar-hide");
        }

    });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

HTML For Navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-home navbar-expand-lg navbar-blue fixed-top py-0">
    <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="logo"/></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="fitness.html">Fitness &amp; Nutrition</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="dropdown" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Membership</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="membership.html">Memberships</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/adm/adm_appt_search.asp?studioid=22296&view=&sSU=&qParam=&lvl=&catid=&prodid=&date=12%2F20%2F2018&classid=0&trn=0&tg=&loc=1&vt=&justloggedin=&pMode=0&stype=&page=&prodGroupId=&optForwardingLink=&nLgIn="><i class="fas fa-user"></i>&nbsp;Client Login</a>
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following style (from `teststyle.css`) when you reveal the navbar:

```
.navbar-hide {
    pointer-events: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.navbar-hide` class has the `pointer-events: none;` css.  That is preventing it from intercepting clicks.

Another thing you  might want to fix:  If you scroll down and refresh your script doesn't check the scroll position and will leave the navbar hidden until you scroll manually.

Comment: Thanks! I am unsure how to go about fixing the second issue.